# Image Slider with Animation Within Frames

Tags: jquery, image, animation, slider

I have a client who wants an image slider for their website. They want to have animations within a few of the frames, but they want it to be functional on iPhones and other mobile media so I cannot use Flash. Is there a simple way to do this? They need 2 different frames animated. I was thinking it might be possible to program the animations with JQuery, but I believe the slider would need be able to trigger the animations. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) is one of the best i know for mobile phones and desktops.
This slider fits the viewport-width automatically. Haven't testen now, but have read positive feedback :)

Ideal for responsive web designs.